# Https on Elastic Beanstalk Without Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to decrease my AWS bill and deactivate load balancing on some of my elastic beanstalk applications. 
I managed to setup https through AWS Certificate Manager with the free Amazon issued certificates.

When I remove the load balancing, I don't have the option to setup the SSL certificate. Any ways to add it somewhere else, like from the EC2 instant linked to EBS?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Is this still not possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use ACM certificates without either a load balancer or a CloudFront distribution. If you don't have either of those, you will need to obtain an SSL certificate through some other means, and install it on your web server software running on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: @Moffen You can also use ACM certificates with API Gateway now, but you still can't install them directly on EC2 servers.